# Modify Azure Service Bus Message set with ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Can a queue message in Azure Service Bus that has been set with ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc be modified or deleted before its enqueued datetime?

In some cases I need to change or delete a message submitted for future delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. But you can cancel a scheduled message if you use a dedicated API added recently. Here's a post about it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2016/07/11/cross-post-canceling-scheduled-messages/

Comment: Thanks Sean!  I'm happy to see ASB team has added this functionality to the api.  I was worried I'd have to abandon using ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc for future messages because there's just too many ways my users might need to change or delete future messages.  So with this new api I should be able to delete the scheduled messages and then if needed submit another message with modifications.